# How to loop through an array of object to finding key values that includes same words-Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of object with textnames

```
array= [{
  text:"ABC",
  someobj:{}
  length: 3
 },{
  text:"XYZ",
  someobj:{},
  length: 4
 },{
  text:"TES",
  someobj:{},
  length: 2
 },{
  text:"ABC_VALUE",
  someobj:{},length: 3
 },{
  text:"TES_VALUE",
  someobj:{},length: 10
 },{
  text:"SME",
  someobj:{},length: 39
 },{
  text:"SME_VALUE",
  someobj:{}, length: 1
 }
]
```

As you can see I have `_VALUE` present in some text names. I'm trying to get the total length of all the matching values, i.e length of "ABC" + length of "ABC_VALUE"(6), similarly length of "SME_VALUE" + length of "SME" (40).

I tried with switch case and if condition.

```
function getVlaues(obj)
let length=0;
    else if(obj.text.includes("SME")) {length += obj.length;}
    else if (obj.text.includes("ABC")) {length += obj.length;}
    else if (obj.text.includes("TES")) {length += obj.length;}

    return length;
}
```

but this does not return me the total length of the 2 object. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your code doesn't include any attempt at iterating over all the objects. You should have a loop of some kind over `array`.

Comment: Do you need to sum ALL the values with the final result as a number or do you want an object with sums for different `VALUE` terms?

Comment: @slider: the later one, "object with sums for different VALUE terms" thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split text on `_` and use the first value as key and calculate length for each key

```js
let array = [{text: "ABC",someobj: {},length: 3}, {text: "XYZ",someobj: {},length: 4}, {text: "TES",someobj: {},length: 2}, {text: "ABC_VALUE",someobj: {},length: 3}, {text: "TES_VALUE",someobj: {},length: 10}, {text: "SME",someobj: {},length: 39}, {text: "SME_VALUE",someobj: {},length: 1}]

let final = array.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let text = inp.text.split('_', 1)[0]
  op[text] = op[text] || 0
  op[text] += inp.length
  return op
}, {})

console.log(final)
```

Or if you're sure the `text` only differs by `_value` in the end then you can replace that part and use as key

```js
let array = [{text: "ABC",someobj: {},length: 3}, {text: "XYZ",someobj: {},length: 4}, {text: "TES",someobj: {},length: 2}, {text: "ABC_VALUE",someobj: {},length: 3}, {text: "TES_VALUE",someobj: {},length: 10}, {text: "SME",someobj: {},length: 39}, {text: "SME_VALUE",someobj: {},length: 1}]

let final = array.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let text = inp.text.replace(/_value$/gi,'')
  op[text] = op[text] || 0
  op[text] += inp.length
  return op
}, {})

console.log(final)
```